# Bootstrap div- align to center of page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a col-span-6 div to the center of the page using Twitter Bootstrap 3. Unfortunately, nothing I do is working. I used Firefox developer tools to discern the issue was most likely stemming from the fact that the col-span-6 class was floated left. Therefore, I added a style="float: none !important;" to the col-span-6 element, but that did nothing.

Help!!

```
<div class="panel-group col-sm-6" style="float: none;">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="card-text">test</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but it seems to me that you wanted to achieve this effect:

```css
.super-center {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  float: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="super-center panel-group col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="card-text">test</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It was enough to add to your div's: `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You can align a div to center of the page using the CSS. Following CSS works for me. You can try using this CSS.

```css
.col-sm-6 {
          position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   border-radius: 3px; 
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group col-sm-6">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
            <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="card-text">test</p>
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` for this to handle alignment in a easier way. I have done a sample code below. Hope it helps you

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-default d-flex h-100">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="card-text">test</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100vh !important;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/bhgx3yzv/

Answer (score 0):

Use column offset with "col-sm-6" to make it in center. Here is an example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
         <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
         <p class="card-text">test</p>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

It automatically push the column in center.